# Generate every possible combination of a set of numbers in C#

Tags: c#, math, grouping, permutation, combinations

I'm looking for a efficient method to generate a combination of numbers in every possible combination.  So, if I had a generic list of integers (1 - 120), I would want one result to actually be all 120 numbers in numerical order from 1 to 120, and then I would need every other combination where those numbers were in different order.

Comment: Have you found or developed a method which is not efficient enough to meet your requirements? And require assistance refining it (so should probably post it) - Or is this just a "pls send teh codes" plea?

Comment: The number of permutations will be hugemongous (namely 120!) and will probably take days to iterate through.

Comment: You realize there are 120! different combinations, right? At 1 million permutations per nanosecond that would still take 1.2e178 years.

Comment: @helloworld922: Better start as soon as possible, then. ;)

Comment: Whichever problem you’re trying to approach is probably NP-complete, meaning it is not computationally feasible to solve using brute force (by enumerating the entire search space). You need to come up with a heuristic or directed search algorithm for solving the problem “intelligently”.

Comment: this situation usually arises when trying to perform some kind of search - if so, please post the original problem so we can help you with a more suited algorithm.

Comment: Only `6 689 502 913 449 127 057 588 118 054 090 372 586 752 746 333 138 029 810 295 671 352 301 633 557 244 962 989 366 874 165 271 984 981 308 157 637 893 214 090 552 534 408 589 408 121 859 898 481 114 389 650 005 964 960 521 256 960 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000` iterations.

Comment: http://www.bearcave.com/random_hacks/permute.html look under Permutation Algorithms

Comment: @L.B: +1 for the calculation of 120! to 170 sig figs.

Comment: @MrWuf: L.B’s calculation is fully precise, not just to 170 significant figures. See [wolframalpha.com/input/?i=120!](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=120!)

Comment: The original issue I was trying to solve is actually this:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145110/probability-involving-unique-group-combinations

Comment: @MikeS if you have a mathematical problem to solve why don't you solve it mathematically and then code that? Coding each, small, individual step can result in the absurdity that you're faced with currently.

Comment: I haven't really figured out a way to solve that with math.  At this point, I'm not just looking for the total number of rounds, but I'm looking for C# code that can actually do the grouping.  I believe it's been called the "Social Golfer" problem.

Comment: I fail to see why this question was closed as “not constructive”. It describes a specific problem which has a specific solution. That the computation of the solution is not computationally tractable does not make the question non-constructive – it is a detail to be pointed out as part of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

For what it’s worth, here’s how it may be done for small ranges (e.g. 1–8) using LINQ and recursion.

If you try increasing the range incrementally, you will realize why this approach won’t work.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[][] combinations = GetCombinations(8).Select(c => c.ToArray()).ToArray();
    string s = string.Join("\n", combinations.Select(c => string.Join(",", c)));
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GetCombinations(int count)
{
    return GetCombinations(Enumerable.Range(1, count));
}

static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GetCombinations(IEnumerable<int> elements)
{
    if (elements.Count() == 1)
        return EnumerableSingle(elements);

    return elements.SelectMany((element, index) =>
        GetCombinations(elements.ExceptAt(index)).Select(tail =>
            tail.Prepend(element)));
}

static IEnumerable<T> ExceptAt<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int index)
{
    return source.Take(index).Concat(source.Skip(index + 1));
}

static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T element)
{
    return EnumerableSingle(element).Concat(source);
}

static IEnumerable<T> EnumerableSingle<T>(T element)
{
    return Enumerable.Repeat(element, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you found a way to do that fast, go and claim a nobel prize.

You just broke every modern encryption mechanism, which is based on a similar primciple - the fact that calculating every possible combination of two (prime) nubmers is not possible fast.

If that is a homework, you got up to a joke. if you really think there is a magic hidden secret we do not tell you, you are - living in delusions.

Sorry, this is one of the issues that just make no sense.

> I'm looking for a efficient method

Define efficient. The most efficient method I can see now is grabbing a TON of computers and go for it with brute force. The NSA supposedly can do that for 128 numbers within an acceptable timeframe now ;)

The seonc alternative, if you ahve limited money, is to go for time. Put in a small machine, with a solar panel, somewhere, and let it calculate for some time. Supposedly per the one true story of the world (as told in "The Hithhikers Guide o the Galaxy) this is why earth exist - to calculate the question to the absolute answerr, which is 42.

THe THIRD way - by far the most efficient - is just to use 42 as answer. If it fits you just found THE question, if not it it just another failure.

Sorry, I HAD to make that non serious. People regularly come with "simple" mathematical questions that just FALL into the factorization type of trap.